# Why do some animals have beards?

Tags: genetics, evolution, zoology, mammals

Why do some animals such as some Goats, Ibex, Orangutan etc, have long well-shaped beard like men?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably for the same reason men have beard.

Comment: Apparently, the "sexiness" of beards is conserved in the animal kingdom.

Comment: @Frieke Some biologists argue that beards have less to do with female choice per se, but more to with intrasexual competition and status hierarchies. So a male beard may have more to do with intidimating other males than females finding them sexy. I'm not saying that this is true necessarily; I just wanted to note  that I have seen it been argued.

Comment: @Eff: yes indeed. Growing a long beard is costly (concerning resources but also potential handicap). Being able to afford a nice beard is showing dominance among males and attractiveness for females. Maybe I should just put this into an answer.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

In humans and animals beard growth is usually restricted to males, since it's dependent on hormones (testosterone or, specifically, according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beard#Evolution) it's dihydrotestosterone). By no surprise it starts growing during puberty.

But why?

Growing a long beard is costly concerning the necessary resources but also because of a potential handicap. Being able to afford a nice beard is showing dominance among males and attractiveness for females. It could be seen as a direct display of high testosterone levels. This is comparable to peacock feathers. They are very impractical, but have great value for showing dominance and attracting females.

I think, there are many psychological theories around to explain the attractiveness of beards. Some might also be meaningful in animals. Apart from cultural, religious or hipster beard trends, we generally consider old men with long beards as wise and knowledgeable. In animals the beard might also signal social status in groups, additionally to male dominance and sexual attraction.

Further reading:

- [Importance of hair in humans and hormones involved](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1529-8019.2008.00214.x)
- [Sexual attraction of beards in humans](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1090513813000226)
- [Trustworthiness of bearded men](https://file.scirp.org/Html/2-6901043_44185.htm)
- [Intrasexual competition influencing sexual dimorphism (here: size)](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/pdfplus/10.1086/285888)
- [Sexual selection](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0960982210015198)
- [Costs and benefits of male hair (lion mane)](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/297/5585/1339.long)

Comment: The research of animal beards is pretty sparse, but hair at the chin is just one of many "appearance traits". So, I provided some studies about various aspects of sexual selection and human psychology that give explanations.

Comment: Further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handicap_principle